# Tensorflow inference on large ndarray: cython or muliprocessing speed-up possible?

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, inference

I've created a system that chooses some 20,000 or so locations that contain classified training data, extracts the values to a DataFrame, and trains and saves a vanilla neural net (mlp).  I then create the large `np.ndarray` that needs inference (`data.shape = (60, 8000, 8000)`), restore the model, and begin a ~6-10 hr for-loop that classifies each location in the 8000x8000 pixel space to produce a classified `ndarray`, `new_array.shape = (1, 8000, 8000)`.

My question is simple: Is there a better way than doing a Python for-loop over the `64*10**6` pixel locations to infer this large pixel space?

Context: This is a project that gathers a feature array from a stack of Landsat images, and samples areas of known land classes according to vector GIS data. Then it infers the rest of the image and writes a new raster with [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio).  The tensorflow multilayer perceptron is [here](https://github.com/dgketchum/IrrMapper/blob/master/pixel_classification/tf_multilayer_perceptron.py), the training array construction is [here](https://github.com/dgketchum/IrrMapper/blob/master/pixel_classification/compose_array.py).

Code: I've tried to remove all cruft.

```
def classify_stack(data, model, out_location=None):

    final_shape = 1, data.shape[1], data.shape[2]

    # reshape, mask np.nan values
    data = data.reshape((data.shape[0], data.shape[1] * data.shape[2]))
    data[data == 0.] = np.nan
    m_stack = marray(data, mask=np.isnan(stack))

    n = m_stack.shape[0]

    new_array = np.zeros_like((data.shape[1], data.shape[2]), dtype=float16)

    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(model))
        saver.restore(sess, model)
        pixel = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n])

        wh = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Wh:0')
        wo = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Wo:0')
        bh = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Bh:0')
        bo = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Bo:0')
        classify = tf.add(tf.matmul(multilayer_perceptron(pixel, wh, bh), wo), bo)

        time = datetime.now()

        ct_nan = 0
        ct_out = 0

        for i in range(m_stack.shape[-1]):
            if not np.ma.is_masked(m_stack[:, i]):
                dat = m_stack[:, i]
                dat = array(dat).reshape((1, dat.shape[0]))
                loss = sess.run(classify, feed_dict={pixel: dat})
                new_array[0, i] = np.argmax(loss, 1)
                ct_out += 1
            else:
                new_array[0, i] = np.nan
                ct_nan += 1

            if i % 1000000 == 0:
                print('Count {} of {} pixels in {} seconds'.format(i, m_stack.shape[-1],
                                                                   (datetime.now() - time).seconds))

    new_array = new_array.reshape(final_shape)
    with rasopen(out_ras, 'w', **meta) as dst:
        dst.write(new_array)
```

Any advice on the structure of my tf model, and possible solutions in other languages (or cython?), etc. would also be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into the tf.data library ([guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), [API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#_tf_data_API))?